# Doughnut chart, in some cases if quantity is 1, its showing without back ground color, but color shows correctly while hovering

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have a doughnut chart in chartjs, with 5 data types. ie "Overdue", "Waiting for me to sign", "Waiting for partner to sign", "In progress" and "Pending". It has corresponding values of 112, 140, 35, 3 and 1 with background colour #FF4657", "#FFD336", "#00DCFF", "#00C597" and"#0062FF". In this case when i produce the graph for pending data which has a value of 1, is showing without any background colour. But interesting thing is while hovering its showing with correct colour

```
labels = ["Overdue", "Waiting for me to sign", "Waiting for partner to sign", "In progress", "Pending"];
backgroundColor = ["#FF4657", "#FFD336", "#00DCFF", "#00C597", "#0062FF"];
data = [ 112, 140, 35, 3, 1];
```

This is the data proportion which gives me this issue.
Here is the image
[image]

And when I zoom in i get this, you can see a narrow blue line there
[image]
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/n7azjuob/1/.

Comment: You are using full width, can you check my image above? Am i getting like that because of that width?

Comment: I gave width 37% in the body in your jsfiddle, and I am getting the issue. S i think its related to width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is being drawn over all of the arcs, so because the value is so small in comparrison with the other values it already has a low percentage and with the border drawn over it, it becomes pixel work and it cant go smaller as 1 pixel so it will start drawing the border over it.

So you can either put the borderWidth to 0 or check the data before visualizing it and remove any data that is soo small that it doesnt visualize correctly.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Overdue", "Waiting for me to sign", "Waiting for partner to sign", "In progress", "Pending"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ["#FF4657", "#FFD336", "#00DCFF", "#00C597", "#0062FF"],
      data: [112, 140, 35, 3, 1],
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 37%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

[image]